# Cost effective way to convert 12v DC to 7.6v DC @2A

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I'm working on a hobby project that involves continuously powering a 5 watt handheld radio for long periods of time off a 12v automotive electrical system (in reality the input will be more like 13-14v).  The battery that comes with the radio is 7.6v and the radio draws ~2 amps during transmission.

The radio is designed to be charged while the battery is attached, however the final solution does not need to include the battery at all.  I plan to connect the output of whatever circuitry I build/buy directly to the contacts on the radio where the battery would normally interface.

What would be the best way to build a voltage regulator for this application relatively cheaply?  I'm not against buying something off the shelf, but I've found very little that is rated above 1000 ma.

**EDIT:** The original body of this question said the radio drew 7.6 amps.  This was a typo, the peak current draw is ~2 amps. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A really fast and easy solution I use alot is the family of simple switchers from NS

Comment: *"in reality the input will be more like 13-14v"* - almost.  In reality, when the engine is running, the input will more likely be 13 to 15 volts with spikes of up to 60V.  You will require an automotive grade regulator that can cope with those spikes.

Comment: Answers or attention to all the following would be appreciated. All are necessary if people are to answer well: Your heading and text don't match. 7.7V x 2A <> 7.6V x 7.6A. Presumably it's 2A on transmit? Makes a difference to the requirement. Will it run well on 6V? Will it run well on 6.4V, will it run well on 8V? Does it have an internal switching power supply - I'd guess yes. If so then what is the permitted Vin range? What is the original battery?  = 2 x LiIOn at 3.8V each? Or ? Do you intend to kep the battery in the radio while operating or replace it entirely with the power supply?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, thanks for the input.  I've corrected the one typo and added a note that I do not plan to keep the battery in the radio while operating.  I don't have the radio with me right now, so I don't know what the acceptable input voltage range is, but will update the question as soon as I find out.  The battery is a single "pack" encased in hard plastic.  I'm not sure how many internal cells it has, but it is listed as 1650 mAh.

Comment: Does "cost effective" include considerations of efficiency? You can do it for under $5 in parts - or not vastly more with somewhat higher efficiency. | IF you can get off the shelf units cheap enough then 2 or 3 in parallel with a little care could be made to work. MAY be cheapest. May. If you can find original battery chemistry OR provide raio spec (always a good idea) we should be able to find out acceptable Vbattery range. | IF about 8 Volts is OK and IF efficiency of not much over 50% is OK (IF) you could do a simple easy supply with 2 x 18650 LiIon in series and a simple float charger.

Comment: Pray tell, that I may be the better edified, why was @nutsfor8051 's  brief but actually exceedingly valuable answer deleted? It pointed people with an utter minimum of extra work to an utterly invaluable resource.

Comment: @Russell: Actually it didn't point anywhere, it only mentioned "NS".  Someone new to this might not now what that refers to.  I also mentioned National and two other companies with more detail in my earlier answer, so I really don't see what it adds.  I agree with Majenko and Mark Rages that it should have been a comment, not a anwer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - it included the "Simple switcher" magic buzz word which when searched on will turn up eg the complete module solution that NS make - which I have mentioned. I took the sentence from his post and plugged it into Gargoyle complete to see what one got and those modules were the 1st hit. I am well aware of the simple switcher iC but not the modues. All they add is an inductor and some guaranteed layout plus Matsemi software suppot -which is qot a lot.

Answer (score 2):

At your power levels (60W), you really want to be looking at a switcher.  Maybe you can find a off the shelf Dc-DC converter for your voltages and power, but probably not.  That leaves making one yourself.  Since this is a one-off a few extra dollars for the chip doesn't matter.  Linear Technology, National (now part of TI), and TI have a decent assortment of buck regulator chips.  For simplicity, go to the Linear Tech site and look around.  At 8A, you will need a chip that drives a external switch as apposed to one with the switch built in, but there are plenty of those.  If I remember right, Linear also has a decent set of app notes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a polished solution, as Olin says, you are likely going to have to roll your own switching DC/DC converter circuit. If you go this route be sure to check out TI's WBENCH designer... You basically put in your power requirements (input voltage range, desired output voltage and amperage, etc.) and the tool will offer you a list of options using TI's regulator chips. You get a schematic and a BOM! It's damn sweet.

The downside is the BOM will assume you want surface-mount chips. If you're like most hobbyists, that's an added challenge. :-)

If you really just want to get something working before you undertake this level of challenge, you could consider using an off-the-shelf inverter to get AC power and then use an off-the-shelf brick to get your required DC voltage. This is a horrible idea for a finished project, as you will be lucky to get a fraction of the battery life a switching converter would offer... But it would let you get the meat of your project done more quickly.

Comment: TI, LT, NatSemi, AD (some now jpined) all have online design software that is powerful and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yoo hoo!
** Buy this** and configure it.

It does **exactly** what you want.

Hello ?
 Hmmm. Nobody listening. Must be Christmas-New Year break.
 Ah well.
 Walks wasy...

---

NOTE: The device below is a **compleat solution** - not just an IC.
 That said - as the IC uses synchronous rectification and internal switches, the only external components are the inductor and glue RC's.
 User has to supply 3 x R and 4 x C.

[TI LMZ14203 3A out buck converter module.](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/simple_switcher_dc_dc_converters/power_module.html)

SIMPLE SWITCHER® **Power Modules** [Not separate ICs but the whole works]

Complete buck regulator waiting for you to set the voltages.

- SIMPLE SWITCHER® DC/DC Converters
  Award-winning SIMPLE SWITCHER DC/DC converters deliver robust power supplies with the minimum set of external components. All SIMPLE SWITCHER products work with the enhanced WEBENCH Power Designer end-to-end design and prototyping tools.

This looks about right

LMZ14201H/02H/03H
1/2/3A out.
Vin 6V - 42V.
Vout 5V up
No derating u to 60C ambient

I'd guestimate 90%+ efficiency at 2A out and 85%+ at 3A out based on datasheet.

Datasheet are application note quality.

[LMZ14203H  datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmz14203h.pdf)
 [LMZ14203  datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmz14203.pdf)
 H has higher Vout max.

[Design page for the 3A out version](http://www.national.com/pf/LM/LMZ14203H.html#Overview)

[image]

[$19.55/1 from Digikey, in stock](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/LMZ14203TZ-ADJ%2FNOPB/LMZ14203TZ-ADJCT-ND/2179598) - Dear - BUT it is the complete unit, barring some "glue" parts.

["News release"  -  NatSemi power modules](http://www.national.com/news/en/0,1735,1440,00.html)

http://www.national.com/pf/LM/LMZ14203H.html#Overview

1/2/3   6 to 42 5 to 30 97  -40 to 125  EN, SS      —   TO-PMOD-

Comment: I was looking for a cost effecitve way to convert from 6V to 3.3...I came across this question and your recommendation.. for this purpose the step down regulator LM2594M would also do the job, right?? (bcoz this is one cheaper than the one u recommeded...)

Comment: @Sathees That depends on what your toatl spec is, whcih you do not say. A link to the IC you intend is always useful. eg [**LM2594M... - datasheet here**](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LM2594MX-12%2FNOPB/296-35398-2-ND/366824)* has about 500 mA max and is about 75% efficient at full load under the conditions you mention. If tyhat suits your need the IC may be OK. [* website gives M suffix part number but HV datasheet.Presumably similar, but do check].

Comment: thx! Well a battery box of 6V will be attached to an atmega328 and a bluetooth module (both should consume less then 0.5A)...therefore I think an LM2594 should be an appropriate option for me, right?

Comment: @Sathee  As above. Check the data sheet but it looks OK. Efficiency can be much better with a synchronous rectifier IC but if 75% is acceptable it shoul;d be OK. IF you cou;d get say 90% then the run time would be about (90-75)/75 = ~~~ 20% longer .

Comment: Thx. can just quickly telle me what you mean with runtime?

Comment: @Sathees - Run time = time that it will run for from a full battery charge. The more efficient the converter is the more time it will operate for. IMPORTANT!!!: when you say it is a 6V battery - what sort of battery is it and how many cells? Could be 3 cell lead acid, 4 cell alkaline, 5 cell NiCd or NimH or other type or cell count. Of the above ONLY the lead acid is anything like 6V across it's discharge range. eg 4 x Alkaline will drop to 4V at end of capacity and the LM2594 only operates down to 4.5V in - so about 5V say min at battery. So please give battery details.

Comment: I have just posted a question considering your question. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185534/run-a-servo-nimh-battery-vs-alcaline-batteries      ...so can you tell me there whether the LM2594  is beneficial one for me or wehther there are better ones?

Comment: I am likely to use 4x1.2 Nimh (4.8V) batteries...what r thebetter buck converters to convert 4.8V to 3.3V than LM2594?

Comment: @Sathees You said 6V battery and now you are saying 4.8V duri ng much of operation and 4V at end of discharge. Even 4 x 1.1V is below spec for that converter. You need to have a sensible spec to start and stick with it if you intend to "design" your designs. And you need to check the data sheet rather than just guess. | The Digikey site has an exceedingly product selector guide that will allow you to identify many of the available ICs. Look there 1st and ask questions if needed once you have. [**Utterly awesome - MAY suit**](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/AP3417C.pdf) In stock 44c in 1's ...

Comment: .... and try [**this search**](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40027%2Cfff8029a&k=buck+synchronous&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=1&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25)  BUT do not be limited to it.